# A checkbox click event is interrupted to run code, but $.trigger('click') will only be recognized in Chrome, not Firefox. Why?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, triggers, click

I have a convoluted scheme to interrupt a checkbox click event, so I can run some javascript/jQuery code before the click event is completed (ie. box is checked).

But, I've noticed some different behavior when applying the code in Chrome (my base browser) and Firefox (used by a smaller set of my users).

In this fiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/hematogones/sgqdqk6n/) , the sequence of events works fine in Chrome, but if you try the same in firefox, the programmatic `.trigger('click')` does not trigger the event listener. Why? I've googled it and perhaps something to do with the `$.trigger()` method?

My code:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="foo"> Clicky!

<hr>

<textarea id="bar"></textarea>

<hr>

<textarea id="cons"></textarea>
```

JS (using jQueryUI dialog)

```js
$("#dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false
});

$("#foo").on('mousedown', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop mousedown propagation
  $("#foo").prop('checked', false).prop("disabled", true); // disable checkbox from checking

  if (!$("#foo").is(":checked")) { // if not checked, run script

    // Open a modal while checkbox event is paused
    $("#dialog").dialog('open').dialog({
      title: "Hey! Here is a modal",
      modal: 'true',
      buttons: {
        "OK": function() {
          // run a script while modal running during checkbox pause
          $("#bar").val("checkbox paused, script run");
       
                       // release checkbox disable  &
          // programmatically complete the check
          $("#foo").prop('disabled', false);
          $("#foo")[0].click(); 
          // This click event completes and the click listener fires below in Chrome, but not on firefox? Why oh why?
          $("#dialog").dialog('close');
       
       }
        
      }
    });
  }
});



$("input:checkbox").on("click", function() {
  $("#cons").val("check completed!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="foo"> Clicky!

<hr>

<textarea id="bar"></textarea>

<hr>

<textarea id="cons"></textarea>

<div id="dialog">
  A modal opens
</div>
```

**Update:**
I simplified my code to the bare elements and I can demonstrate the behavior is specific to launching the dialog (or alert or any modal), which breaks the subsequent .trigger('click') method in firefox.
[simplified example](https://jsfiddle.net/hematogones/Lrhy7q3b/)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to disable the checkbox?
When you close the modal, it takes some time to change `disabled` property back to `false` (in Firefox). So we need to wait until the checkbox is enabled again. Otherwise the trigger 'clicks' on the disabled checkbox with no result.
Look at the snippet, I've set a timeout on the trigger and it works:

```js
$('#bar').on('click', function() {
  $("#foo").prop('disabled', true);
  alert("pause"); // alert, modal, dialog all break trigger event
  $("#foo").prop('disabled', false);
  // wait...
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#foo").trigger('click')
  }, 100);
});

$("input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
  $("#baz").val("check completed!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="foo">
<hr>
<button id="bar">Checker</button>
<hr>
<textarea id="baz"></textarea>
```

But it could be solved a different way.

Comment: All hail the hypnotoad!! This is exactly what I've been looking for - thank you very much. As for the use case, I admit it is somewhat convoluted, but within my limits as a hobbyist programmer, it seems to be the most straigtforward solution to me.  In my case, my users will interact with my web app via a menu of mouse clicks. Based on certain earlier selections, I need to modify the effect when my checkbox click listener fires -which is why I pause the checkbox by disabling -> running some code --> finishing the click sequence. I'd love to know a better way to do this generically though.

Comment: I'll be giving your bounty as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: I'd suggest you look at Promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise